# Jacobian ideal as primary idea;

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, complex-geometry, singularity-theory

Let $R = \mathbb{C}\{x_1, \dots,x_n\}$ be the ring of germs of analytic functions and let $f \in R$ be a homogeneus polynomial of degree $p$ such that $\sqrt{Jac(f)}=\langle x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}\rangle \subset R$. If we know that $Jac(f) \subset R$ is a primary ideal, can we conclude that $\sqrt{\langle \partial_1 (f), \dots, \partial_{n-1}(f) \rangle}= \langle x_1, \dots, x_{n-1}\rangle$ as well?

Comment: Just to clarify: by $\text{Jac}(f)$ do you mean the ideal generated by $f$ and its first partial derivatives?

Comment: Yes, and since $f$ is homogeneous, $Jac(f)$ is simply generated by the partial derivatives of $f$.

Comment: Aha, I missed the hypothesis that $f$ is homogeneous.

Comment: Although I am not sure that this condition is really important for the actual question, I left it since it might be easier to solve.